# Unable to open dependencies file SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sirishortcuts, xcode-build-settings

Im working on a iOS objc app with Siri Shortcuts. I got everything working properly **but** when I add an Intents Extension (to handle background support) and try to run the app I get an error.

The IntentHandler of the Intent Extension only has the default implementation.

The error:

```
Exiting early, found no Swift version in executables.
error: unable to open dependencies file (/.../.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/App Name.build/Debug-iphoneos/ShortcutExtension.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep)
```

In Build Phased:

- Extension is included in Target Dependencies.
- Extension is included in Embed App Extension.

ps: Clearing the DerivedData, clean build, clean project and restarts does not work.

I really don't know how to solve this problem. Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution myself.

To solve this issue you have to go to Extension > Build Settings and set Always Embed Swift Standard libraries to NO.

Then clean the project and build the app will make the errors disappear (at least it did for me).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In my case, I have a single view iOS app with half a dozen Pod imports. Once I set all the targets plus the Pods project to NO, the unable to open dependencies file error went away. Didn't even have to clean the folder again.

Comment: turn what to NO?