# Xcode Flutter build: unable to open dependencies file (..../Runner.build/DerivedSources/.d)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, app-store-connect

We have to upload our flutter application on the AppStore Connect in order to publish on the AppStore. When we build the application from Xcode we get this error: unable to open dependencies file (..../ios/DerivedData/Runner/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/.d)

How can we solve the error?

Cleaned build folder
Switched to release setting
Pod deintegrate
Pod update

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51499666/8144311